# Getting Connection Refused Error while triggering POST request to tensorflow serving hosted inside docker

Tags: docker, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I needed to serve multiple tensorflow models with the help of tensorflow serving.
I compiled tensorflow serving in docker.
Next I ran the docker image which ran successfully.

Remaining steps of running the docker container and hosting multiple models I did by following the 
below tutorial:
https://medium.com/@brianalois/how-to-setup-tensorflow-serving-for-production-3cc2abf7efa

The models and config file required for this operation were provided by the author of the blog in the following git repository:
https://github.com/brianalois/tensorflow_serving_tutorial

I put the config file and the models in the following locations inside my docker container:

```
root@72d81d939de5:/tensorflow-serving# ls
AUTHORS  CONTRIBUTING.md  LICENSE  README.md  RELEASE.md  WORKSPACE  configs  models  tensorflow_serving  third_party  tools

root@72d81d939de5:/tensorflow-serving# ls ./configs
models.conf

root@72d81d939de5:/tensorflow-serving# ls ./models 
iris  xor

root@72d81d939de5:/tensorflow-serving# ls ./models/iris
1  2
```

Note: Folder 1 and 2 contained saved_models.pb files for iris classification and iris prediction models respectively.

As mentioned in the tutorial I ran the server in the same port as mentioned in the tutorial:

```
tensorflow_model_server --port=8500 --rest_api_port=8501 --model_config_file=/tensorflow-serving/configs/models.conf

The log shows:
Successfully reserved resources to load servable {name: iris version: 1}
```

Inside the config file the base paths for the models hosted were defined like this:

```
model_config_list: {
  config: {
    name:  "xor",
    base_path:  "/tensorflow-serving/models/xor",
    model_platform: "tensorflow",
    model_version_policy: {
        all: {}
    }
  },
  config: {
    name:  "iris",
    base_path:  "/tensorflow-serving/models/iris",
    model_platform: "tensorflow",
    model_version_policy: {
        all: {}
    }
  }
}
```

Next from outside the docker container, I trigerred the following POST request for the iris prdict model:

```
curl -X POST \
  http://localhost:8501/v1/models/iris/versions/2:predict \
  -d '{
 "signature_name": "predict-iris",
 "instances":[
  [5.1, 3.5, 1.4, 0.2]
 ]
}'
```

And received the following error:

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8501: Connection refused
```

I am not sure what went went; also going by the blog I could not quite understand this POST request string
used here:

```
http://localhost:8501/v1/models/iris/versions/2:predict
```

It will be really helpful if you guide me how to rectify this issue and get expected prediction back from the model.

Comment: It seems like its only loading version 1. Can you try the same command with http://localhost:8501/v1/models/iris/versions/1:predict.

Comment: And normally your docker container has its own local IP. You'll find it by running this command:
docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' container_name_or_id
Try to use this IP instead of localhost.

Comment: @Thommy257 : Thanks for the guidance; I made the changes you suggested and triggered the request again and I am not seeing that connection error anymore! However, it is now throwing a new error: { "error": "Serving signature name: \"predict-iris\" not found in signature def" } -- Any clue how to resolve? Thanks in advance!

Comment: when you use your model exporter to generate your .pb files, you have to define a a signature_name. The signature name in your request has to match exactly this signature_name.
I guess you've used an other signature_name for exporting the graph.

Comment: @Thommy257 thanks! This error is gone now. Could you please guide me what should be the exact format of the client request? I am running tf serving from within docker and I use the following to send request while only single model is there in the container:python client.py --server=172.17.0.2:9000 --image_path=<image_folder>